# Make footfullcite to show up the reference stepwisely when I use "onslide"

Tags: beamer, biblatex

```tex
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article {ssy1975, AUTHOR = {Schoen, R. and Simon, L. and Yau, S. T.}, TITLE = {Curvature estimates for minimal hypersurfaces}, JOURNAL = {Acta Math.}, FJOURNAL = {Acta Mathematica}, VOLUME = {134}, YEAR = {1975}, NUMBER = {3-4}, PAGES = {275--288}, MRCLASS = {53C40 (49F10)}, MRNUMBER = {423263}, MRREVIEWER = {Robert Gulliver},}

@article {fischer1980, AUTHOR = {Fischer-Colbrie, Doris and Schoen, Richard}, TITLE = {The structure of complete stable minimal surfaces in {$3$}-manifolds of nonnegative scalar curvature}, JOURNAL = {Comm. Pure Appl. Math.}, FJOURNAL = {Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics}, VOLUME = {33}, YEAR = {1980}, NUMBER = {2}, PAGES = {199--211}, MRCLASS = {53C40 (58E12)}, MRNUMBER = {562550}, MRREVIEWER = {Themistocles M. Rassias},}

@article {peng1979, AUTHOR = {do Carmo, M. and Peng, C. K.}, TITLE = {Stable complete minimal surfaces in {${\bf R}\sp{3}$} are planes}, JOURNAL = {Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)}, FJOURNAL = {American Mathematical Society. Bulletin. New Series}, VOLUME = {1}, YEAR = {1979}, NUMBER = {6}, PAGES = {903--906}, MRCLASS = {53A10 (53C42)}, MRNUMBER = {546314}, MRREVIEWER = {F. J. Almgren, Jr.}, }

@article {chodosh2023, AUTHOR = {Chodosh, Otis and Li, Chao}, TITLE = {Stable minimal hypersurfaces in R4}, JOURNAL = {To appear in Acta. Math.}, FJOURNAL = {To appear in Acta. Math.}, VOLUME = {}, YEAR = {2023}, NUMBER = {}, PAGES = {},}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{} \begin{itemize} \item<tri@1-> Property of minimal graph: they are stable as hypersurfaces. \textit{Question: classify stable complete minimal hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\leq 8$}. \onslide<2->\item<tri@1-> Attempts: for $n\leq 6$, additionally with {\color{blue}volume growth condition}, they must be hyperplanes (\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\subscriptsize} Simon, Schoen, Yau \footfullcite{ssy1975}). \textit{Question: can volume growth condition be dropped for $n\leq 6$?} \onslide<3-> \item<tri@1-> "It must be hyperplane": for $n=3$, by \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\subscriptsize} {\color{red}Fischer-Colbrie&Schoen} \footfullcite{fischer1980} and \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\subscriptsize} do Carmo-Peng \footfullcite{peng1979} independently; Recently, for $n=4$, by \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\subscriptsize} Chodosh&Li \footfullcite{chodosh2023}. \end{itemize} \end{frame}

\end{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks] \printbibliography[heading=none] \end{frame}
```

I would like the references to show up one by one when I use "onslide", however, my code only shows all the references in every page. How do I change this?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please test your code before posting!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article {ssy1975, AUTHOR = {Schoen, R. and Simon, L. and Yau, S. T.}, TITLE = {Curvature estimates for minimal hypersurfaces}, JOURNAL = {Acta Math.}, FJOURNAL = {Acta Mathematica}, VOLUME = {134}, YEAR = {1975}, NUMBER = {3-4}, PAGES = {275--288}, MRCLASS = {53C40 (49F10)}, MRNUMBER = {423263}, MRREVIEWER = {Robert Gulliver},}

@article {fischer1980, AUTHOR = {Fischer-Colbrie, Doris and Schoen, Richard}, TITLE = {The structure of complete stable minimal surfaces in {$3$}-manifolds of nonnegative scalar curvature}, JOURNAL = {Comm. Pure Appl. Math.}, FJOURNAL = {Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics}, VOLUME = {33}, YEAR = {1980}, NUMBER = {2}, PAGES = {199--211}, MRCLASS = {53C40 (58E12)}, MRNUMBER = {562550}, MRREVIEWER = {Themistocles M. Rassias},}

@article {peng1979, AUTHOR = {do Carmo, M. and Peng, C. K.}, TITLE = {Stable complete minimal surfaces in {${\bf R}\sp{3}$} are planes}, JOURNAL = {Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)}, FJOURNAL = {American Mathematical Society. Bulletin. New Series}, VOLUME = {1}, YEAR = {1979}, NUMBER = {6}, PAGES = {903--906}, MRCLASS = {53A10 (53C42)}, MRNUMBER = {546314}, MRREVIEWER = {F. J. Almgren, Jr.}, }

@article {chodosh2023, AUTHOR = {Chodosh, Otis and Li, Chao}, TITLE = {Stable minimal hypersurfaces in R4}, JOURNAL = {To appear in Acta. Math.}, FJOURNAL = {To appear in Acta. Math.}, VOLUME = {}, YEAR = {2023}, NUMBER = {}, PAGES = {},}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{itemize} 
\item<1-> \only<1->{\footfullcite{ssy1975}}
\item<3-> \only<3->{\footfullcite{fischer1980}} and \only<3->{\footfullcite{chodosh2023}}. 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]
\printbibliography[heading=none] 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]